# Can't see sections in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a table view with multiple sections, but for some (presumably dumb) reason only the first section is visible on my table view.

```
var labels = ["label1", "label2"]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    var sectionHeader = ""
    if section == 0 {
        sectionHeader = "first section header"
    } else if section == 1 {
        sectionHeader = "second section header"
    }
    return sectionHeader
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel!.text = labels[0]
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.textLabel!.text = labels[1]
    }

    return cell
}
```

The header for the first section appears along with a cell with label text "label1" but the second section is no where to be found.

Is there some sort of setting I am not setting? What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: All of this looks OK... Are you sure your entire table view's on the screen?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I didn't change the size of the table view or anything like that.

Comment: If possible share your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good , Few things you can check

1> Tableview's frame is not large enough to fit 2 section and it's not scroll-able also.

2> heightForRow delegate method or viewForHeader or heightforHeader returns 0 or nil

3> Your constraints are breaking at runtime and that's why tableview is not visible properly (you need to check console at runtime)

You can start visual debugger of XCode at runtime and see if your table view is not hidden by some other component etc... (Debug View Hierarchy)